# gengetopt and Automake

Tags: c, autotools, automake, getopt

I'm trying to include the generation of the **cmdline.c** file (from gengetopt's defaults) in my **Makefile.am** file.

The file currently reads like these:

```
bin_PROGRAMS = myprog

myprog_SOURCES = main.c cmdline.c
myprog_DEPENDENCIES = gen_cmdline $(myprog_SOURCES) # somewhere I read that setting DEPENDENCIES inhibits automake from calculating those

gen_cmdline:
    gengetopt < myprog.ggo
```

However, if I modify just **myprog.ggo**, the **cmdline.c** and all its dependents won't get recompiled. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is `gen_cmdline` a .PHONY target?  If `gengetopt` creates a file named `cmdline.c`, then your Makefile.am should probably look like:

```
bin_PROGRAMS = myprog

myprog_SOURCES = main.c cmdline.c
BUILT_SOURCES = cmdline.c
cmdline.c: myprog.ggo
    gengetopt < $(srcdir)/myprog.ggo
```